# Mounting a webDAV share by users

Tags: mount, webdav, davfs2

How do I make a webDAV share mountable, so that is available for all users? without having to type in a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directory that you want to use as your mount point, for example `myserver`:

> sudo mkdir /media/myserver

Add the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

> myserverip /media/myserver/ davfs noauto,user,rw 0 0

Change `myserverip` to the IP address or domain name and port of your webDAV server.

Open `~/.davfs2/secrets` (per user) or `/etc/davfs2/secrets` (system wide) and find the credential line section, now add a line with the server ip, the username you need to login to the webDAV share and the password in the following order:

> myserverip webdavusername webdavpassword

Set the correct permissions on `~/.davfs2/secrets` or `/etc/davfs2/secrets`:

> chmod 600 ~/.davfs2/secrets

or

> sudo chmod 600 /etc/davfs2/secrets

run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure davfs2` and select yes to allow mounting by non-root users.

check that in `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` you have:

```
dav_user        davfs2           # system wide config file only
dav_group       davfs2           # system wide config file only
```

add your user (my username in this example) to the davfs2 group:

> sudo usermod -aG davfs2 myusername

You can check that it you have been added to the group by running `groups myusername`:

```
myusername : myusername davfs2
```

Reboot or log out to let the group changes come in effect.

You should now be able to mount your share by clicking on it in your file browser.